# How to make each <li> toggle with <ul>

Tags: jquery, html

How can I make just one `<li>` toggle per `<ul>`. What is happening with this code is that all `<ul>` tags are being rendered. which also renders all the `<li>` tags. I want one `<li>` to toggle when its corresponding `<ul>` is clicked on.

code:

```
<script>

   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("ul").click(function(){
         $("li").toggle();
      });
   });

</script>


<body>
   <ul>Toggle between hide() and show()</ul>
   <li>This is a paragraph.</li>
   <ul>Toggle between hide() and show()</ul>
   <li>This is a paragraph.</li>
<body/>
```

Comment: well, for one, your li needs to be inside a ul.

Comment: your HTML is invalid. start there.

Comment: And your UL can't contain text that isn't within a li

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the current event source as [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/), also put `li` in `ul`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CL7dM/)**

*Html*

```
<ul>Toggle between hide() and show()
    <li>This is a paragraph.</li>
</ul>
<ul>Toggle between hide() and show()
    <li>This is a paragraph.</li>
</ul>
```

*Javascript*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("ul").click(function(){
           $("li", this).toggle();
      });
});
```

**Edit:** To toggle on when ul is click but not li

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CL7dM/7/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("ul").click(function (evt) {      
        if(evt.target.tagName != 'UL') 
            return;
        $("li", this).toggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Although. When I click the li tag it slides back up. It needs to only slide up when the user clicks on the ul tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("ul").click(function(){
      $(this).find("li").toggle();
});
```

and move `li`'s inside `ul`:

```
<ul>
    <li>This is a paragraph.</li>
</ul>
```

Actually you should entirely refactor your HTML, because it doesn't make any sense ( and it is invalid ). But JavaScript code ( which triggers something inside something else ) is like the one above.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, missed that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one `li` you don't need a `ul`.
The `.toggle()` function is deprecated in jQuery 1.8.

Try this:

```
$(".trigger").click(function(){
   var obj = $(this).next();
   if($(obj).hasClass("hidden")){
      $(obj).removeClass("hidden").slideDown();
   } else {
      $(obj).addClass("hidden").slideUp();
   }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="trigger">Toogle</div>
<div class="elem hidden">Content</div>
<div class="trigger">Toogle</div>
<div class="elem hidden">Content</div>
```

CSS:

```
.elem { display:none; }
```

See demo here: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eSFBu/3/)**